# Redshift: SqlAlchemy error on DateDiff call

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, amazon-redshift

I keep getting an error on a Redshift `DATEDIFF` call. I've succeeded with SQL Workbench when connected to the same Redshift server. Unfortunately, I'm not doing so hot using SQLAlchemy, and I was hoping I could get some help on here. Please let me know if you need more details.

---

With the Class Definition of `MyTable`,

```
class MyTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'my_table'
    __table_args__ = {
        'schema': 'elm'
    }
    tstamp = Column(TIMESTAMP(timezone=True), nullable=False)
```

I'm trying to find the last twelve hours of **tstamps** on **my_table** where the value is older than **12 hours** than the **latest tstamp value**. (`datediff(hour, max(tstamp), tstamp) > 12`)

```
# Get the most recent timestamp
max = session.execute(select([func.max(MyTable.tstamp)])).first()[0]

# Label the calculated column that will determine the difference
l = func.datediff('hour', max, MyTable.tstamp).label('z') # have also tried `text('hour')`

# Get the query
z = session.query(MyTable).filter(
    MyTable.tstamp.in_(
        select(
            [distinct(MyTable.tstamp), l]
        ).where(
            l >= 36
        )
    )
)
```

However, I keep getting this error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: 
(psycopg2.ProgrammingError) 
function pg_catalog.date_diff("unknown", timestamp with time zone, timestamp with time zone) does not exist
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. 
You may need to add explicit type casts.
```

Here's what my SQL looks like when I print to console. Using `SQL Workbench` for the `Redshift` server gives me the results I expect.

```
[SQL: '
    SELECT elm.my_table.tstamp AS elm_my_table_tstamp 
    FROM elm.my_table
    WHERE elm.my_table.tstamp IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT elm.my_table.tstamp, 
        datediff(%(datediff_1)s, %(datediff_2)s, elm.my_table.tstamp) AS z 
        FROM elm.my_table 
        WHERE datediff(%(datediff_1)s, %(datediff_2)s, elm.my_table.tstamp) >= %(param_1)s)
'] 
[
    parameters: {
    'datediff_2': datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 2, 19, 15, tzinfo=psycopg2.tz.FixedOffsetTimezone(offset=0, name=None)), 
    'param_1': 12, 
    'datediff_1': 'hour'
    }
]
```

---

Imports:

```
from my_package import MyTable
from sqlalchemy import select, func, distinct, extract, text
```

---

RESULT:

```
max = session.execute(select([func.max(MyTable.tstamp)])).first()[0]
session.execute(MyTable.__table__.delete().where(
    MyTable.tstamp.in_(
        select([distinct(MyTable.tstamp)]).where(
            func.datediff('hour',
                          cast(MyTable.tstamp, TIMESTAMP(timezone=False)),
                          cast(max, TIMESTAMP(timezone=False)))
            >= 12
        )
    )
))
```

(I wanted to delete the rows I found)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`DATEDIFF`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_DATEDIFF_function.html) does not support the `timestamptz` type. The `timestamptz` type is a recent addition to Redshift. You need to cast it to a `timestamp` instead, e.g. (not tested)

```
func.datediff("max", max.replace(tzinfo=None), cast(MyTable.tstamp, TIMESTAMP(timezone=False)))
```

Comment: cool, so the `CAST(tstamp, TIMESTAMP(timezone=False))` eliminated the error, but I still am not getting the results. +1 for the help, but I still have to solve the problem

Comment: @J.D. I think you're using `DATEDIFF` backwards. `DATEDIFF(..., a, b)` gives you `b - a`, not `a - b`.

Comment: you're absolutely right. 2/2. Can I give you two votes?